# Saving data with CreatePHP in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, createjs

I'm trying to implement https://github.com/flack/createphp with Laravel 4.

I have have a view which outputs some data from the database:

```
<div class="row editable content" property="sioc:content" data-placeholder="Enter some content..." contenteditable="true" data-medium-element="true">
```

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper bibendum tellus at commodo. Nam fermentum odio posuere nulla gravida, quis placerat augue sodales. Vivamus sagittis, ligula eget eleifend congue, nibh erat fermentum neque, a consectetur dui libero imperdiet elit.

I am not sure how to use https://github.com/flack/createphp with Laravel to then save the data once the orgional data has been updated. Like in http://createjs.org/demo/hallo/

I have added `midgard/createphp": "0.9.*@dev` in `composer.json`

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Cheers,
Chris